# Unable to view configured session in the session window of HermesJMS

Tags: hermes-jms

each time I try to configure a session in HermesJMS it does not appear in the  session window. I can still see it in the session drop down if I select to create a new session however it gets dropped from the main view where I want to view it in order to be able to create topics, etc. any ideas. I've attached a screen shot so that you can see what I mean

the below is what I have created:

[image]

the below is what I can see - which is only file

[image]

Its unclear where the other ones are?!!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue it is related to part of the config not being required - it doesn't error it just doesn't show the session as being viewable. which isn't great